# create thread but process shows up?

Tags: c++, multithreading, process

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <thread>

void test_cpu() {
    printf("thread: test_cpu start\n");
    int total = 0;
    while (1) {
        ++total;
    }
}

void test_mem() {
    printf("thread: test_mem start\n");
    int step = 20;
    int size = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10Mb
    for (int i = 0; i < step; ++i) {
        char* tmp = new char[size];
        memset(tmp, i, size);
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("thread: test_mem done\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::thread t1(test_cpu);
    std::thread t2(test_mem);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `g++ -o test test.cc --std=c++11 -lpthread`

I run the program in Linux, and run top to monitor it.

I expect to see ONE process however I saw THREE.

[image]

It looks like std::thread is creating threads, why do I end up with getting processes?

Comment: What makes you certain those are processes rather than threads?  Use `H` to toggle thread display in `top` -- any change?

Comment: @G.M. what... I thought PID means process ID. How can top mix them together.. OK, thanks so much

Comment: On a side note, `test_mem()` is leaking memory, is that intentional as part of your test?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have no idea. It's borrowed code. Thanks for checking that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux does not implement threads. It only has Light Weight Processes (LWP) while pthread library wraps them to provide POSIX-compatible thread interface. The main LWP creates its own address space while each subsequent thread LWP shares address space with main LWP.

Many utils, such as HTOP (which seems to be on the screenshot) by default list LWP. In order to hide thread LWPs you can open `Setup (F2)` -> `Display Options` and check `Hide kernel threads` and `Hide userland process threads` options. There is also an option to highlight threads - `Display threads in different color`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]